# GmailApp.search: Need to fetch all emails within a single thread

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the GmailApp.search function to scan my inbox and retrieve the last 50 mails matching a specified label, and print on a Google Sheet.

```
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox label:HGO", 0, 50);

  for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) 
  {
    sheet.appendRow([threads[t].getLastMessageDate(), threads[t].getId(), threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject()])
  }
```

The problem is that a whole thread of emails is considered as a single email only.

In the example below, the single mail thread consists of 25 emails:

[image]

Whereas the output to Google Sheets is just a single row of data:

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve all 25 emails on the Google Sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- From your sample image, I thought that in your case, the messages are included in the thread.
- When `appendRow` is used in the loop, the process cost will be high.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) 
{
  sheet.appendRow([threads[t].getLastMessageDate(), threads[t].getId(), threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject()])
}
```

To:

```
var values = [];
for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
  var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();
  for (var m = 0; m < msgs.length; m++) {
    values.push([msgs[m].getDate(), msgs[m].getId(), msgs[m].getSubject()]);
  }
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### References:

- [getMessages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages())
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)